# Transactions count issue of Custom variable GA

Tags: javascript, php, magento, google-analytics, e-commerce

I have an issue with GA custom variable. 
I inserted the following code snippet to source of HTML.

`_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'AgencyType', '<Agency Type Sample>', 3]);`

Full JS code on the page:

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<account #>']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'AgencyType', '<Agency Type Sample>', 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();`
```

This code is included to every page of Magento. 
But when I check my Analytics it shows me the next result
[image]

If you look at the transactions column you will notice that there are 39 of 66 transactions. So I would like to ask why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

You used `doubleclick.net` scripit,but browser ad block ( http://adblockplus.com ..) has block `doubleclick.net` site.

It is not perfect reason for this problem.

But many other brower install ad block software, 
so you can use google tag manager, or other transaction capture solution.

( I am working for china customer but China has `great fire wall`, so we don't trust ga or someting )